# How to take coordinates from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I need to take the coordinates from the `locations` table and replace them with my data `53.4015174, 44.967495`

```
SELECT P.* 
    FROM PRODUCTS AS P
        LEFT JOIN MERCHANTS AS M ON (M.MERCHANT_ID = P.STORE_ID)
        LEFT JOIN CATEGORIES AS C ON (C.CATEGORIES_NAME = P.CATEGORIES)
        LEFT JOIN LOCATIONS AS LO ON (LO.LOCATION_ID = 20)
            WHERE P.CATEGORIES ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['Cameras']) AND
                ST_DWithin(M.LOCATION::geography, ST_GeogFromText('POINT(53.4015174 44.967495)'), LO.RADIUS, false)
                GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID, M.MERCHANT_ID
```

Comment: `UPDATE locations set col1=54.401574, col2=44.967495 WHERE id = ?` is not what you want?

Comment: @bjk116 No, since I need to take from the location table, since I took the radius from the location table

Comment: I need you to be as explicit as possible here because I am slightly confused.  What is the table your updating lets call `Table1`, and what table has the correct data, `Table2`, that you want to put into `Table1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firtly SRID set  this query 4326 use it;

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829),4326);

SELECT P.* 
    FROM PRODUCTS AS P
        LEFT JOIN MERCHANTS AS M ON (M.MERCHANT_ID = P.STORE_ID)
        LEFT JOIN CATEGORIES AS C ON (C.CATEGORIES_NAME = P.CATEGORIES)
        LEFT JOIN LOCATIONS AS LO ON (LO.LOCATION_ID = 20)
            WHERE P.CATEGORIES ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['Cameras']) AND
                ST_DWithin(M.LOCATION::geography, ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829),4326))
                GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID, M.MERCHANT_ID
```